# Angular2 - no animation in API

Tags: animation, angular

My question is - has something changed since Angular2 went out of beta? I see no Animate in API and no information about what exactly will happen with that.

Could you give me an answer is there something announced about animation? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

Animation support became available in Angular2 RC.2

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

**original**

`AnimationBuilder` should be available from `@angular/platform-browser`. `Animation` seems to not be exported.

I guess this is because the new Angular-animation module is about to be shipped.

Comment: I still do not understand. Is the animation available to use now? In API there is only ```@angular/platform-browser/index``` and ```@angular/platform-browser/testing```.

Comment: RC2 now includes the animation API: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

Answer (score 1):

For now, a workaround would be to

```ts
import {AnimationBuilder} from '@angular/platform-browser/src/animate/animation_builder';
```

Comment: So animation is available to use but is not documented yet in API (but will be), right?

Comment: Right. but they might be planning something else altogether, who knows. Same has happened to some other classes too